# how to access the file with modified url in php?

Tags: php

I want to access a file with my modified url without going via .htaccess

Let assume my file is in

```
root/newfolder1/xyz.php
```

So the url below is working fine

```
www.abc.com/newfolder1/xyz.php
```

I want to access the file in newfolder1 but with modified url like below:

```
www.abc.com/xyz.php // This I want but it is not working.
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: And why don't you want to use .htaccess for this?

Comment: Symlink `/newfolder1/xyz.php` to `/xyz.php` ?

Comment: .htaccess re-write is in order... Impossible without it

Comment: @Thanks for the reply but @ JIJOMON K.A gave me the solution. I am going to try it.

Comment: @ kerbholz Thanks for the reply. But how to do it with Symlink?

Comment: His answer is not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Platinum Not quite *impossible*, but it's the most straight forward solution. Anything else would be bending over backwards for no (?) reason.

Comment: @Thank for the reply. The solution is not working for me. Is it really impossible without .htaccess?

Comment: In Linux: go to your `root` folder, type `ln -s newfolder1/xyz.php ./xyz.php` to create a symlink. In Windows: no clue. Make sure your webserver can "FollowSymLinks"

Answer (score 1):

You can either use symlink

Or you can make a php in your main folder
xyz.php

And include the php inside the newfolder1/xyz.php

Using this method make sure to change working dir to newfolder1 before including.